# Stun with quotes in xml

Tags: xml

Can someone explain one stunning thing for me? I have xml-file generated in a c# programm which then I load int osome web resource and it works fine. But when I open xml-file in notepad I see quotes in element data instead of `&quot;`. But when I create xml-file in notepad manualy and leave quotes web resource doesn't accept it until I replace quots with `&quot;`. I don't understand why generated xml-file works fine without `&quot;`? I tried to open xml-file in several text editors all of them show quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity reference `&quot;` is never needed in text nodes; it is only needed in attribute values, in the case where `"` has been used as the attribute delimiter. You can write `&quot;` in text nodes if you want, but it's not necessary, so any tool that rewrites the XML will probably not use it.